# Windows XP PRO SP3. Setup ASP.NET dev. environment

Tags: iis, sql-server, windows-xp, asp.net

I have Windows XP PRO SP3 And Visual Studio 2010. 
By default I have IIS 5.1. And there is no option to upgrade it.

I want to start developing ASP.NET.
Could any one give a good reference how to properly setup IIS and SQL server on my computer.

Currently to setup IIS + SQL Server + VS, seems not so simple as to setup Apache + MySQL(POSTGRESQL) + Eclipse(Netbeans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Windows XP then there is no way to upgrade IIS on this OS.

> IIS is shipped with the Windows Operating System and somewhat coupled
>   with the Operating System. You are not able to upgrade IIS complete
>   version on your current operating system.

There is only option available to use some features of IIS 7 is II7 Express with your Visual Studio 2010.

Another is create virtual machine of Window 7 with microsoft virtual machine to using complete features of IIS 7 and if you you somewhat advance user then configure your debugging environment between your windows xp and the virtual machine OS (windows 7).

Check these links for reference:
[Running a WebSite using IIS Express from the Command prompt and Visual Studio Integration](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.com/2011/09/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none.html)
[Running IIS Express from the Command Line](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919843/how-do-i-install-iis-express-7-5-onto-windows-xp

> There is no problem in connecting IIS to sql server.. just some
>   connection related problems and missing connection drivers can cause
>   problem. if everything is correct then all will work fine.

**EDIT: By comments**
SQL Server is not a part of IIS. It needs license to use and installed separately except Express Edition that is provided with Visual Studio. If you are installing Visual Studio then you can select SQL Server 2008 Express Edition to install with it.

If you do not want to install Visual Studio then you can get SQL Server Express Edition separately on Microsoft website. you just need `MDAC` (Microsoft Data Access Component) to establish connection between SQL server and IIS.

In ASP.net, Add this under the  tag to specify connection string. here `.\sqlexpress` is your SQL Express default instance name if you install sql server with your visual studio installation or  your `computername\sqlexpress`.

Here is some installation steps for [sql server 2005](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-2005-installation-guide-for.html) standard edition and for [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143722%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)  [2008 R2 - step by step](http://www.sqlserver-training.com/sql-server-2008-r2-express-edition-installation-with-screenshot/-).

and [download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) SQL Server management studio express to work easily with databases and search on google "how to attach database sql server management studio"  then connect your web application to sql server database using following stuff to check connection etc.

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConStr" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Pooling=true;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Access this connection string with name ConStr in your asp.net code using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"]` as:

```
SqlConnection con;
 using (con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString()))
{
//Data Manipulation code
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I simply don't understand if sql server is installed with iis or not, or how to install it, or how to connect it. Should repeat that regarding to MAMP, WAMP, LAMP, Denwer and straight installs are far more info than about MS servers.

Comment: There is a seperate installation for SQL Server...Just install it SQL Server is not part of the most recent versions IIS ( including the one included with Windows XP ).

Comment: if you want to use php with IIS then you have disable asp.net and enable CGI setting running php.. and connection string will change for mysql and other type of database providers. it may possible you have to use some drivers provided by microsoft to connect with mysql. ..

Answer (score 2):

IIS 5.1 is fine for ASP.Net development.

IIS is tied closely to Windows and is only becoming (slightly less) separated in Windows 2008 R2. For now, with Windows XP, you are limited to using 5.1

I would recommend either using a virtual machine if you want to use a different version of IIS, or alternatively, download [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038) for Windows XP. This is not full IIS, but, for most development needs (excluding plugins/similar), it is good enough.

Comment: Yeah, I'v already installed yesterday IIS Express. I think so. But The gui was a little bit uncomfortable for me. Also I didn't understood if sql server was installed or not?

Comment: You do understand the gui would be pratically the same for a "full" version of IIS right?  I do not believe IIS Express can communicate with a full version of SQL Server, I do believe it can communicate with SQL Server Express